# SQL Query to get records of parent table that have a list of child records

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, hierarchical-data

I have two tables in an MS SQL Server 2005 database, parent and child, where the parent may be related to many child records. [Child.parent_id] is related to [parent.id]. The child table also has column [foo] I need to bring back all records in the parent table where [child.foo] matches on each of one to many parameters. For example I would like all parent records that have a [child.foo] value of 'fizz' and a [child.foo] value of 'buzz.'
I have tried the below query, but it is returning records that match on only one.

```
SELECT     Parent.ID
FROM         Parent 
INNER JOIN Child ON Parent.ID = Child.parent_id
WHERE     (Child.foo = 'fizz')
UNION ALL
SELECT     Parent_1.ID
FROM         Parent AS Parent_1 
INNER JOIN Child AS Child_1 ON Parent_1.ID = Child_1.parent_id
WHERE     (Child_1.foo = 'buzz')
```

Comment: I have specified the database. I just assumed the solution would be database agnostic, but I don't need it to be.

Comment: Recursive CTEs are the ANSI standard, but implementation lags - only 3 dbs support `WITH`: Oracle, SQL Server and DB2.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This will return all Parent records which have [at least] one child with a 'fizz' foo AND [at least] one child with 'buzz' foo.  Which is what I think is required in the question.

Also, while being potentially sub-optimal, this query is generic in a sense that it will work with most SQL implementation, not only the more modern ones, where the support of CTE, subqueries and related constructs are supported.

```
   SELECT DISTINCT Parent.ID
    FROM Parent
    JOIN Child C1 ON Parent.ID = C1.parent_Id
    JOIN Child C2 ON Parent.ID = C2.parent_id
    WHERE C1.foo = 'fizz'
      AND C2.foo = 'buzz'
```

**Edit**:
Now that Joel Potter has fixed the query in his answer, we probably agree that his approach has several advantages over the query listed above (please give him a few +reps).  In particular:

- the *structure* of the query doesn't change when we add, or remove, targeted values for the column foo.
- the query is probably more easily optimized [by the server itself]
- the structure of the query allows it to handle variations on the definition of the filter.  For example we can query all Parents which have children such that say 2 of 5 possible values of foo are present.

Following is Joel's query here, slightly modified, to show how it can be expanded for more than 2 foo values.

```
SELECT Parent.Id
FROM Parent
INNER JOIN Child on Parent.Id = child.parent_id
WHERE Child.foo IN ('fizz', 'buzz')  -- or say, ... IN ('fizz', 'buzz', 'bang', 'dong')
GROUP BY Parent.Id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Child.foo) = 2  -- or 4 ...
```

Answer (score 9):

I believe you want something like this.

```
Select 
    Parent.Id
From Parent
    inner join Child on Parent.Id = child.parent_id
Where 
    Child.foo = 'fizz' or Child.foo = 'buzz'
Group By
    Parent.Id
Having
    count(distinct Child.foo) > 1
```

Here's the test script:

```
Create Table #parent ( id int )
Create Table #child ( parent_id int, foo varchar(32) )

insert into #parent (id) values (1)
insert into #parent (id) values (2)
insert into #parent (id) values (3)

insert into #child (parent_id, foo) values (1, 'buzz')
insert into #child (parent_id, foo) values (2, 'buzz')
insert into #child (parent_id, foo) values (3, 'buzz')
insert into #child (parent_id, foo) values (1, 'fizz')


Select 
    #parent.Id
From #parent
    inner join #child on #parent.id = #child.parent_id
Where 
    #child.foo = 'fizz' or #child.foo = 'buzz'
Group By
    #parent.Id
Having
    count(distinct #child.foo) > 1        

drop table #parent
drop table #child
```

Returns only Id 1.

Comment: This query would fail if a given Parent had, for example, two (or more) children with a foo value of 'fizz'

Comment: @mjv: You are correct. Replace the `count(*)` with `count(distinct Child.foo)` to correct that.

Comment: right on.  I edited my answer to point to your -now fixed- solution, as I find it more generic and more [automatically] optimizable.  The query plan however on this type of query would greatly depend on specific SQL implementation and specific statistical profile of the data.

Comment: @mjv: I'm uncertain about the performance of grouping vs. joining. If you have benchmarks that would be great to see. You're probably right about the specific RDBMS being a factor though.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to share this simple generalization of Joel's excellent answer. The idea here is to be able to pass an arbitrary table of 'target' children into a procedure as either a table valued parameter or split delimited string. While this is nice, it would also be nice to have a similar query that matched using LIKE instead of IN.

```
--Parents whose children contain a subset of children

--setup
create table #parent ( id int )
create table #child ( parent_id int, foo varchar(32) )

insert into #parent (id) values (1)
insert into #parent (id) values (2)
insert into #parent (id) values (3)

insert into #child (parent_id, foo) values (1, 'buzz')
insert into #child (parent_id, foo) values (1, 'buzz')
insert into #child (parent_id, foo) values (1, 'fizz')
insert into #child (parent_id, foo) values (2, 'buzz')
insert into #child (parent_id, foo) values (2, 'fizz')
insert into #child (parent_id, foo) values (2, 'bang')
insert into #child (parent_id, foo) values (3, 'buzz')

--create in calling procedure
declare @tblTargets table (strTarget varchar(10))
insert into @tblTargets (strTarget) values ('fizz')
insert into @tblTargets (strTarget) values ('buzz')

--select query to be called in procedure; 
--  pass @tblTargets in as TVP, or create from delimited string via splitter function
select #parent.id       --returns 1 and 2
    from #parent
       inner join #child on #parent.id = #child.parent_id
    where #child.foo in (select strTarget from @tblTargets)
    group by #parent.id
    having count(distinct #child.foo) = (select COUNT(*) from @tblTargets)        

--cleanup
drop table #parent
drop table #child
```

Answer (score -1):

This should get the results you want:

```
SELECT p.ID
FROM Parent p
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1 FROM Child c WHERE c.parent_id = p.ID AND c.foo IN ('fizz','buzz')
)
```

Comment: Although the question is ambigous, I think the OP would like the Parents which have both a 'fizz' `AND` a 'buzz' child.  The query above will return parents that have either a 'fizz' `OR` a 'buzz' child.

Comment: Ah, you're probably right. As such, I'm up-voting your answer.