# Operand should contain 2 column(s) when fetching data through JPQL using IN & MEMBER OF clause

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jpql, hibernate-mapping

I am trying to fetch data of employee availability creating a query. I have used @ElementCollection annotation to map skills and daysAvailable, which stores data into other table.

```
TypedQuery<Employee> query = entityManager.createQuery("select e from Employee e where :day MEMBER OF e.daysAvailable and :list MEMBER OF e.skills ", Employee.class);//
        query.setParameter("day", dayOfWeek);
        query.setParameter("list", employeeRequestDTO.getSkills());
        List<Employee> list = query.getResultList();
```

I am trying to pass a set in my query. If there is only one element in set then the query works but if more then 1, then it is not able to fetch. I have tried using **e.skills in (:list)** instead of 
**:list MEMBER OF e.skills**. But still no luck!!

```
@Entity
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @Nationalized
    private String name;

    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @CollectionTable(name = "skills", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "emp_id"))
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Set<EmployeeSkill> skills;

    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @CollectionTable(name = "days", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "emp_id"))
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Set<DayOfWeek> daysAvailable;

// Getters & Setters
```

This is the domain i have created and now want to fetch all employees who are available on a particular day and have particular skills. I have created query for this but it is showing error - **java.sql.SQLException: Operand should contain 2 column(s)**

This is the query generated-

```
select  * from employee e where ( 'TUESDAY' in ( select d.days_available from days d where e.id=d.emp_id)) and (( 'PETTING','FEEDING' ) in (select s.skills from skills s where e.id=s.emp_id));
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JPQL, `MEMBER OF` takes a single argument and checks if that's contained in the provided collection.

Check out the [Hibernate User Guide](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-member-of-collection-predicate) for more details.

Try this query instead:

```
select e 
from Employee e 
join e.skills s
where 
    :day MEMBER OF e.daysAvailable  and
    s in :list
```

Comment: Hi Vlad, how can i fetch record that match all the values in list and not just any value??

Comment: Check out [this StackOverflow question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165119/sql-query-to-get-records-of-parent-table-that-have-a-list-of-child-records) for more details.

Comment: Hi Vlad, the list of values will be dynamic. So, i am not sure how to implement the answer mentioned in the link you gave, as they are passing  single value as parameter.

Comment: You can pass the list dynamically to the IN clause and the list size to the GROUP BY clause as well. It's not easy, but doable.

Comment: Hi Vlad, thanks for your help. I was able to do it using the link you shared. Thank you so much!! :)

Comment: I'm glad I could help.